# Using the spell animate object, I want to create an iron cobra but cant seem to

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, constructs

Using the spell [animate object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-objects), I want to create an [iron cobra](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/cobra-constructs/iron-cobra) (or something that works just like it).

No where in the pages of listed rules (see my related post for the pages) does it discuss the abilities the snake has, which are "find target" and poison. Now the one page does talk about using the [universal monster rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules) and poison is found there, but not find target.

Since the Iron Cobra is listed as 2 CP and has 2 abilities I expect they should both be worth 1 CP each, but I cant actually find these rules.

Where are the abilities of an iron cobra and their associated cost?

Answer (score 8):

While you can make variant constructs using *animate object* and *permanency* using the [alternative construct creation rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs), there's no provision for making super custom ones like the iron cobra.

While it's all on one page in the PFSRD, there are two fundamentally different rulesets at work here.  One is originally in Haunting of Harrowstone, and that just lets you trade construct size, in the form of CP, for a limited set of abilities (grab, burn, etc.), and lets you stick *permanency* on them to keep them around.  It's reprinted in Ultimate Magic.

Right after those rules in Ultimate Magic is a completely separate set of rules for building new constructs.  Those rules use **CR** - *not CP* - and have you basically just monster-build as a base.  An iron cobra does not have '2 CP', it is CR2. There is no specific pointed-out list of all construct abilities.  Only the ones listed in that first ruleset are allowed for the animate object-based creation.  Anything in the MM or beyond is allowed for creating constructs, but that's basically like creating new monsters (and is subject to your GM approval).

So you can create a slightly varied animated object with *animate objects* and *permanency*, or you can create an iron cobra with Create Construct and the usual list of requirements.